# How to use data from one function in another function?

Tags: python

I am a *beginner* and had a question related to using function data with other functions.

Say that a function `my_list` generates a list as well as a sublist. I want to know how to access items from the sublist of that list generated by the function and use the numbers to compute a sum of them in the other function. I have tried things like

```
def compute_sum(myNewlist): #myNewList is the list generated by the other function#
     for i in myNewList:
         addup += i
```

but I really am not well versed enough yet in python to think about how to do this. I guess what I am asking is how to call elements in a sublist to another function?

edit - just going to drop the code here for more understanding from repliers!

```
fyle = input('Enter the file name you want to process: ')

def read_data(fyle):
    with open(fyle) as file:
        
        for line in fyle:
            lne = [line.strip().split() for line in open(fyle).readlines()]
            newlist = [[elem[1], elem[0], elem[2]] for elem in lne]
         
        
        print(newlist)
        
read_data(fyle)

def compute_sum(newlist):
          ???
```

edit 2 - also the list looks like

`mylist = [[Smith, Bob, 18], [Jorgen, Peter, 14]]` - to this, i am looking to extract and add the numbers, not the strings

Comment: Could you give a small example how the other function looks like and what it's returning. If you want to use the list and the sublist outside of that function you should return both.

Comment: @Matthias Ok i added the rest of the program.

Comment: A function can return a value. Instead of  `print(newlist)` do `return newlist`. And when you call the function: `ret_data = read_data(fyle)`. That what you mean?

Comment: @jacobgalam I think thats in the right direction, so I would then use ret_data as the parameter for compute_sum?

Comment: @tehtay If `newlist` is need to be a parameter for `compute_sum`, yes

Comment: @jacobgalam I dont know if newlist has to be the parameter is a bit of what im saying. like if i were to use ret_data as the variable for read_data(), wouldnt i have to make ret_data the parameter for compute_sum?

Comment: what `read_data` need to do? `newlist` is `[[Smith, Bob, 18], [Jorgen, Peter, 14]]`?

Comment: @jacobgalam read_data opens a file from dir , makes a list out of the items in the file. I need compute_sum to take the 14 and 18 from the list above right and add those two together. I try this:
```
def compute_sum(newlist):
    some = sum(newlist)
```
but error because unsupported operand type when adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example rewrite of your code that I think demonstrates what you're asking:

```
fyle = input('Enter the file name you want to process: ')

def read_data(fyle):
    lne = [line.strip().split() for line in open(fyle).readlines()]
    newlist = [[elem[1], elem[0], elem[2]] for elem in lne]
    return newlist

def compute_sum(newlist):
    s = sum([int(x[0]) for x in newlist])
    return s


list = read_data(fyle)
sum = compute_sum(list)
print(sum)
```

Data file `/tmp/data.txt`:

```
line1_item1 10 line1_item3
line2_item1 20 line2_item3
line3_item1 30 line3_item3
```

Result:

```
Enter the file name you want to process: /tmp/data.txt
60
```

Comment: Yes this works good for the function thank you! Quick question - do you always have to assign a variable to your functions? Or is that only when you use return for values inside the function?

Comment: You don't have to use a variable in either case.  If you only end up using the variable once, you can almost always get rid of the variable.  So here, you could use `return [[elem[1], elem[0], elem[2]] for elem in lne]` and `return sum([int(x[0]) for x in newlist])`.  Putting things in variables first is a little more readable sometimes, and better for beginners, but not necessary if you want your code as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work to compute the sum. As mentioned in your post above, I have considered mylist = [[Smith, Bob, 18], [Jorgen, Peter, 14]].

```
def compute_sum(new_list):
     sum=0
     for item in new_list:
          sum=sum+int(item[2])
     #print(sum)
     return sum
```